# Capture group names with regex

Tags: haskell

I'm trying to use the regex package (with TDFA) and the only reference I can find for named captures group is a quasi quoter (cp) and no explanation.
Basically I have regexs in a config files, compiled at runtime with compileRegex, applied to lines and I'm looking to extract a couple of specific captures group out of that, with names I do know at compile time.

So I'm looking for a function that would take the `Matches a`, a string (the capture group name) and would return I guess a `Maybe a`, depending on whether that capture group did match or not ? Or even just a way to extract the capture group names from the `Match a`, that would be enough.

The doc mentions the quasi quoter cp, but no explanation as to how it's supposed to be used, and I'm not even sure I could use if if I knew because I compile my regex at runtime.

Would anyone have examples with named capture groups ?
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll find the API you need in the [Text.RE.Replace](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/regex-1.0.2.0/docs/Text-RE-Replace.html) docs; I think one of the functions with names that start with `capture` will be what you're looking for. Here's an example:

```hs
module Main where

import Data.Text
import Text.RE.Replace
import Text.RE.TDFA.String

needle :: CaptureID
needle = IsCaptureName . CaptureName . pack $ "needle"

main :: IO ()
main = do
  re <- compileRegex "-${needle}([a-z]+)-"
  let match = "haystack contains the -word- you want" ?=~ re
  if matched match
  then print $ captureText needle match
  else print "(no match)"
```

Comment: Ah ! I didn't think of looking in Replace, that's a weird place to put it imho. Thanks a lot, that works perfectly :)